# Need to test SwiperJS component and jest throws an error

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, swiper.js

this is what I have in my test file and have no idea how to fix it was searching everywhere could not find the solution

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { ImageGallery } from '../index';

describe('Swiper has to render', () => {
  test('Will Swiper render', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(<ImageGallery />);
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

having this in my test file

having an error
like that

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.


   

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      1 | /* eslint-disable import/no-unresolved */
      2 | import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
    > 3 | import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
        | ^
      4 | import ImageViewer from 'react-simple-image-viewer';
      5 |
      6 | import 'swiper/css/bundle';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/ImageGallery/ImageGallery.js:3:1)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am struggling right now